# Excel, exclusion of repeated cells while finding max?

Tags: excel

I have a range of cells from B10 to B10000 the first 100 cells are significant values then the next 5 cells are insignificant consisting time and series no. This repeats in remaining cells i want to find the maximum of significant values excluding the insignificant 5 cells that repeat?

Comment: Without actual sample data it would be hard to suggest something practical. In particular is there anything that would differentiate the insignificant values? For example for the time you can do a check if its a date/time and exclude it this way but not sure for the other values. The only other way I can think of is if you explicitly exclude those cells in your formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but it hasn't been tested. It should return only the highest value.

EDIT: Tested and works.

```
Sub FindMax
    Dim i as integer
    Dim j as integer
    dim k as integer
    Dim MyValues(10000) as long 'Use redim preserve I'm too lazy to look it up
    Dim maxValue as long
     'loop through your values, skip 5 every 100
    j = 0
    For i = 100 to 10000
        if k = 100 Then 
            i = i + 5
            k = 0
         end if

        if not k = 100 Then
            MyValues(j) = [SheetName].Range("B" & i)
            j = j + 1
            k = k + 1
        end if
    Next
    ' You now have an array with only your values you wanna look at
    ' We loop through and find the biggest value in there
    for i = LBound(Myvalues) to UBound(Myvalues)
         if myvalues(i) > MaxValue then MaxValue = myvalues(i)
    next
    msgbox MaxValue
End sub
```